# RAW processing programs for Canon 6D

Tags: raw, compatibility, adobe-camera-raw, canon-6d

I am getting a Canon 6D next week and would like to check what my RAW processing program options are, other than the in-the-box Canon Digital Photo Professional.

I am currently using Photoshop Elements 9 for my Canon 60D.  Will I be able to process Canon 6D RAW files as well, or will I need to upgrade to Elements 11 or Lightroom 4 ?

Comment: I personally always use DPP for the raw as I think it does a great job

Comment: Couldn't agree less with the above comment. DPP is painful as part of a real workflow, it is slow and cumbersome. It might do a good job, but taking 2-300% more time then Lightroom just isn't worth not spending the small amount to purchase Lightroom.

Comment: you could always try image view plus more. I made it work with a 6D image from dpollit - lowest footprint editor and viewer with photoshopesque features  :)

Comment: Completely agree with @dpollitt -- DPP is a royal pain to work with, and terrible at dealing with large numbers of photos.  I have a friend who swears by DPP but I have to say - Lightroom just makes everything so easy - and I can't say I have anything to complain about with LR.  It may not have the 'magic sauce' of DPP but it's amazing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to upgrade Lightroom or Elements, as only the latest versions support the 6D.

The Canon 6D [requires Camera Raw 7.3](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html), which is compatible with

- Lightroom 4.3
- Photoshop CS6

According to Adobe, Photoshop Elements 11 only [supports ACR 7.0-7.2](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html).  However, it [appears](http://barbarabrundage.com/2012/12/13/adobe-updates-camera-raw-for-pse-11/) the 7.3 update may be applied to PS Elements 11.

Comment: Hi MikeW, thanks for the Adobe link, really very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Gday.

I had to update my LR3 to LR4 since Adobe didn't make a newer ACR (adobe camera raw) that would support the 6d (ACR for LR4)

LR4 is good for playing with colours and exposure. 
It's pretty useless for image masks and fancy photoshoppy stuff.

So both programs are useful to have.

DPP is also useful to have as its quick preview is super quick.

If I were you I'd google for whether the ACR avail for your Adobe products work for the 6d and get a trial of LR4 and PSE 11

Also, LR4 has a mapping thingo so you can view your pics on google maps. This is handy.
Canon also gives you the MapUtility which does the same (but you need to install the zoombrowser or whatever software to get it)

Comment: Hi Oscar de Lellis , thanks for your comments ! i will try them out !

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux or Mac, you can try [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) which supports 6d since version 1.1.2. Free as in free beer / free speech. (I'm not associated with them, I just happen to think it's very good piece of software).

Comment: hi Macie, Darktable sounds like an interesting app!

Answer (score 0):

My 3c of personal experience....

I had a 5Dii. Found DPP slow, but also I was moving all my workflow and computing over to Linux. Darktable, Rawstudio - some excellent software alternatives in the Linux world.

Then the 5Dii shutter died .. at under 8,900 clicks. Quote for repair was equal or more than a used one on auction sites.  sigh

Went out and bought a 6D as they were on special. For once I got the lowest price since release (its gone up again due to exchange rates).

6D - lovely camera. I actually like using it more than the (heavier) 5Dii.

In-box CD .. coasterware. The previous versions of Canon software were Ok-ish, this was all based and tied to SilverLight, which is banned from my systems since 2006. Even Microsoft are telling people not to use it anymore (2015) and move on.

All the raw processing packages which I tested in Linux came up with an non-removable green tinge for Canon 6D images. I got hold of the devs - all use a common library 'dcraw', which is being worked on. Canon changed the raw format and do not reveal any info (as with printers and scanners), so this has to be reverse engineered for Linux.  I have no doubt this will get fixed, but it will then take time to trickle down to the packages and the distros.

So in the meantime .. I shoot carefully on JPeG. :(

Comment: I use ufraw and have been able to remove a green tint that I found with AWB. I set a manual white balance and seem to have solved that problem.